# Select sub queries within a select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

```
insert into time_test(Difference) values 
(select ((select actual from time_test where id = :p13_id)  - 
(select 
(monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday) from time_test where id= 
:p13_id 
)) from time_test where id= :p13_id)
```

`Difference` is a column in `time_test` which is null, and :p13_id is a page item for Oracle Apex.

I know I need to wrap it in `nvl` or some function like that but I don't know how.

Comment: Why are you using subqueries? Will the value actually be null, or will there be no matching rows? Are you actually inserting a new row into the same table you are querying - with only one column in the insert statement - or are you perhaps actually trying to update that column based on other values in the same row?

Comment: Now that you question that I think I am trying to update the row .

Comment: update time_test set difference = actual - 
  (select(monday+Tuesday+Wednesday+ Thursday+Friday)) where id = :p13_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're actually trying to do an update, not an insert:

```
update time_test
set difference = actual - (monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday)
where id = :p13_id
```

If any of the 'day' columns might be null then you can use [`nvl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NVL.htm) or [`coalesce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COALESCE.html) to default them to zero so they don't break the calculation:

```
update time_test
set difference = actual - coalesce(monday, 0) - coalesce(tuesday, 0)
  - coalesce(wednesday, 0) - coalesce(thursday, 0) - coalesce(friday, 0)
where id = :p13_id
```

You could also do `coalesce(actual, 0)` but it might make more sense to leave the difference null if that is not set. It depends what you want to see in that case.

---

In this case the `nvl()` and `coalesce()` functions are equivalent. If the first argument - e.g. `monday` - is null then the second argument is substituted. So `nvl(monday, 0)` will give you the actual value of `monday` if it is not null, but will give you zero if it is null. You will get the same effect from `coalesce()`, but that allows a list of multiple expressions to be evaluated and will return the first non-null value from the list.

---

Another approach to this is to make `difference` a virtual column that is calculated on the fly, or calculate it in a view over the table; either would remove the duplicate data storage and the need to maintain the value yourself. And if you did definitely want a physical column you could set it from a trigger so automate the maintenance in case any of the other columns are updated outside your Apex application. But a virtual column is probably simpler and neater.

Comment: Can you please explain nv1() ? I dont fully understand it . When performing operations I have set the default values to 0 but if I had 500 page items it would be very difficult to set all 500 to 0 and if I dont set it to 0 . The results are wrong .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `nvl(monday, 0)` will evaluate the value of `monday` independently for each row affected by the update; and for each row, if that row's column value is null then it will substitute zero, for that row only. You seem to be updating one row at a time anyway. (No idea what you mean about "performing operations I have set the default" I'm afraid).

Comment: I didn't exactly know what a nvl function was . I started googling it and I understood it . It helped me out a lot . I wasn't able to perform any operation because of the stupid null values . I have always thought of null as 0 instead of the absence of a value ,so i kind of forgot about it .